# Why short circuit doesn't takes places in a homopolar motor?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries, short-circuits

In a [homopolar motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homopolar_motor) we directly connect copper wire to a battery without any resistance with a magnet in bottom, so why doesn't a short circuit takes place?

Comment: When we say, "short circuit," we're talking about a [_wiring fault_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_fault). The "motors" describe on the Wiki page that you cited all draw lots of current, and quickly deplete the battery, but we don't call it "short circuit," because it isn't a fault when the circuit behaves as intended.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a dead short.

There is some resistance at the contacts of the moving parts and also the internal resistance of the battery.
The battery can warm up but also drain fairly quickly due to the current being larger than that which the battery was designed for.

The movement of the conductor in the magnetic field  will result in a back emf being induced which will also limit the current.

There are [many types of homopolar motors](https://www.google.com/search?q=diy+simple+homopolar+generator&client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALiCzsYoZqBHrJYsYMRWV1wWH18RrAPcRQ:1663409882619&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiAkK3ZzJv6AhVMhFwKHdmzD7MQ_AUoAnoECAEQBA&biw=1548&bih=906&dpr=1.2) that you can make.